# Filter expressions on attribute table

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, expression

I'm new on QGIS, I have shapefile for the whole country and also have for Province down to City/Municipalities, is there any way on attribute table where I can filter using an expression for example:

`"PROVNAME" = 'CEBU'`, but this only for one area.

I tried adding multiple areas, like  `"PROVNAME"  =  'CEBU' 'others' 'others'`.

So basically tried that multiples areas, but getting an error:

```
Parser Error:
syntax error, unexpected STRING, expecting $end

Eval Error:
No root node! Parsing failed?
```

Is there anyway I can select multiple areas by expression, so I can extract from a large area shapefile, I'm trying to filter it from country down to province and cities, so I can extract it easily.

Answer (score 7):

From what I understand, what you are looking for is:

```
"PROVNAME" IN ('CEBU', 'others', 'others')
```

This will work, but it might not be the best solution if you are trying to select a large number of areas.

Comment: Very cool, I did not know you could make an expression like this. I   learned something new today!

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the OR operator.  Your expression would be

```
"PROVNAME" = 'CEBU' OR "PROVNAME = 'ABRA' OR "PROVNAME" = 'Whatever'
```

Without that OR you will get a parsing error ( I tested my string expression without the OR and got the exact same error msg as you )

[image]

** Obviously our field names are different, but you want to format your expression like above